# Caddy webserver Brotli example

Tags: caddy, brotli

I was trying to deploy my angular2 app with brotli compressed distribution to Caddy webserver.

Are there any examples for the caddy webserver with Brotli compression support?

Answer (score 2):

Caddy currently only serves [pre-compressed](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/issues/525#issuecomment-269908548) Brotli files.

So first make sure you have an installation of [Google's Brotli tool](https://github.com/google/brotli).

Then generate Brotli-compressed copies of your files with

```
/path/to/bro --input example.html --output example.html.br
```

Please note: Make sure to not delete the original.

Caddy will automatically serve the Brotli version where available and the raw version otherwise, it would also be helpful to do the same with pre-compressed gzip, though Caddy can also gzip-compress [on the fly](https://caddyserver.com/docs/gzip).